# NodeMCU : Input pullup in A0

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to port a simple project I have working in an Arduino UNO to a NodeMCU but I am stuck as I am using the analog gpio to receive the input from some buttons, I am always getting always low values (between 0 and 5) while in the working arduino sketch I get values from 0 to 1023.

I have tried deactivating the wifi while trying to retrieve the values, but I got no luck trying that, as I have read that sometimes the NodeMCU A0 gpio malfunctions when the wifi is not sleeping.

I am setting up the gpio in the setup method like this:

```
void setup(void){
    pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT_PULLUP);  
    ...
```

And my sensorPin variable is declared in the beginning of the sketch

```
int sensorPin = A0;
```

Any ideas why when I read the value in the NodeMCU I don't get the same behaviour as in an Arduino board?

Comment: Probably because the nodemcu isn't an arduino. Internal pullups on analog pins is an AVR quirk that you cannot rely on being the same on other mcus.

Comment: Sorry if I am asking really basic questions, as I am starting in this field. The final objective is to put all the code inside an esp8266, as they have an analog gpio, and I was using the nodeMCU because it was easier for me to push the code there. Is there any way to get the right analog values I get in an arduino in a nodeMCU?

Comment: The obvious way is to use an external pullup. You can guarantee it will be there then.

Comment: Reading the documentation here (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins) it says that they use a 20K resistor when we activate by software the pullup resistor. I will try to use an external pullup as you have suggested. Thank you!

Comment: You're confusing Arduino with NodeMCU. NodeMCU is a completely different beast running with a different chip from a different manufacturer with a different core architecture. You cannot use Arduino documentation for low-level things like chip internals when looking at a completely different chip. That's like using a Ford manual to try and fix your VW.

Comment: What I meant is that I was activating the pullup resistor in the arduino analog gpio, and to get a similar effect I need to put an external pullup resistor in the NodeMCU to get the same values as I am getting in the Arduino. Would this work or internally the analog gpios work so differently that I won't be able to get same behaviour?

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Yes, try and keep the same value as the internal one. However the internal one could be anywhere between around 10k to 50k or more.

Comment: I just wrote this blog post you might find interesting: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/measuring-arduino-internal-pull-up-resistors/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by Majenko in the comments, I thought that all MCUs analog gpios had a pullup resistor built in, so I have been able to solve the problem using an external pullup, in this case connecting a 10K resistor like in the diagram:

[image] .

Special thanks to Majenko for his time and patience. Cheers!

Comment: Did you have to connect the R1 across VCC (5v)? Would it still work with a 3.33v pin or should I need a lower resister in that case?

Comment: @ΕГИІИО I used the 3.3 V pin in my final project with the nodeMCU so you should be good with the same resistance. Cheers!

Comment: @PayToPwn Alternatively, you can short the A0 pin with any digital pin and pull-up that digital pin. In fact, INPUT_PULLUP on analog input pin is very useful. In that way, you can connect photo-resistor directly to the analog pin and measure light intensity without external resistors.